# echo $? behaves differently

Tags: c, shell, sh

I have this C program:

```
int main() { return 10; }
```

After running this when I write `echo $?` in the terminal its prints `10`.

Now suppose I have a `.sh` file:

```
echo $?
```

After running the C program if I run the `.sh` file it prints `0`.

Why?

Comment: How do you run your script? Also please show the content of your script.

Comment: I think they print 0 because after you start your bash skript $? gets another value

Comment: it is like a brand new shell, where no comands are run, being the first command exactly `echo $?` - hence 0

Comment: The script file contains only one line: `echo $?`. I run like this: `sh 01.sh`

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay in that case `echo $?` print the exit code of the last command of your script and as there is no last command, the status is `0`. Run `source 01.sh` if you want to have the exit code of  `./tst` displayed.

Comment: @ouah But why does it print 10 when I directly write in the terminal?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay I think when you run a .sh file it will start a new instance of sh, run it, and finish. Because it won't run in the actual isntance it doesn't know about the exit code of your C file

Comment: @ouah Got it. Thanks! Can you suggest some good online books to learn shell programming?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: [here's a pretty thorough howto](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) on shell scripting

Comment: Try to end your script with `exit $?`, then the caller will also get the same status code returned

Answer (score 2):

Simple: the `.sh` file gets executed by bash, or some other shell. That binary (`/bin/bash` or wherever it is) executes the script and then exits. If the shell binary exits successfuly, it returns *0* to the system
after your bin returned 10 to the system, and you execute your .sh file, a new shell process starts up (and this shell did not execute your program). So `echo $?` probably echoes the return value of another process that the executing shell instance ran (login, or whatever...)

the command `echo $?` echoes the value that the exit code the last program you executed returned. In case of your C program, it returns 10, so you see 10 show up. Your `.sh` file, though is executed by another binary, that returns 0 (upon success), hence `echo $?` shows 0.

Suppose you do this:

```
./your_bin
./your.sh
echo $? 
 //--> echoes 0
./your_bin
echo $?
  //--> echoes
```

If you execute a binary inside a bash script, and what your script to *"forward"* the exit code of that binary, than simply write:

```
#!/bin/bash
./your_bin
exit $?
```

A side-note: returning random ints from a program isn't the greatest of ideas. exit codes *mean* something. That's why the C standard lib defines 2 macro's:

```
printf("%d vs %d\n",
    EXIT_SUCCESS
    EXIT_FAILURE
);
```

Guess what, `EXIT_SUCCESS` shows up as 0, `EXIT_FAILURE` is 1.

Comment: If the `.sh` is executed by a binary, how can it return before the  whole `.sh` program is executed?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: Added that to my answer, just add `exit $?` or `exit 123`, if 123 is the exit code you want

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: Sorry, misread your comment: it can't: if the binary is still running, then you can't get its exit code, because it hasn't executed. The script _can_ get the exit code if the binary was started from within that script, though... that's what I added to my answer... but honestly, if you write a C program that does something like `system("/home/user/bash_script.sh");`, what's the point of using C anyway?

Comment: You said, "Your .sh file, though is executed by another binary, that returns 0 (upon success), hence echo $? shows 0." My question is how can the binary which is executing the `.sh` file return before the whole `.sh` is executed?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: your .sh file doesn't execute itself: it's a script that is interpreted by a binary (ksh, zsh or bash or whatever shell you're running). if you, inside that script echo `$?`, it'll echo the exit code of the last binary that was executed, that needn't be the one that is running your script. You can't echo the exit code of the process that is running your script, from within that script, but from the command-line, you can do `./my.sh && echo $?`

Comment: If you write a shell script that only does `echo $?`, it'll probably echo 0, too, because the shell started without errors... `$?` is like saying to the shell: _"You know that last process you ran... now that it's gone, what was its last message?"_

Comment: Yes! That's the answer that I wanted! Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: In that case, if this answer answered your question, would you mind awfully marking it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the exit value of your c programm, start your c programm also in the .sh file, and then make echo $?

```
./c_prog
echo $?
```

The value of $? is the exit-value of the last command. If you start your bash script, which contain only echo $?, they don't have a last command.

Comment: I'm afraid it does not answer the question.